# 2D C Arrays in JNI

Tags: java, c, arrays, java-native-interface, 2d

When I fill this 2d array called `map[][]` and try to print out all the values stored in it I get a null character after each actual array character. This shouldn't be the case, I would like all characters in the `mapFromJava` array to be in the same layout in the map variable.

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_CGameLogic_fillMap(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jobjectArray mapFromJava) 
 {
      jsize len1 = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, mapFromJava);
      int i;
      for(i=0; i<len1; i++) {
          jcharArray array = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env,mapFromJava, i);
          int len2 =(*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);
          jchar *mapArray = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, array, 0);
          int size =  (sizeof(jchar) * len2);
          memcpy(map[i], mapArray, size);
     }
}
```

map is a 2d char array.
This is the print function:

```
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_CGameLogic_printMap(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint mapHeight, jint mapWidth) {
int y;
int x;
for (y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
        printf("%c", map[y][x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

}

Comment: What is the type of ```map```? It should probably be ```wchar_t**```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how you determined there are extra null bytes, but keep in mind a jchar is a 16 bit value as java characters are UTF-16. That means characters in the ASCII range will consist of a null byte and the ASCII byte.

**Update**
Your output should be stored as wchar_t not char as a jchar is a 16 bit value and a C char is 8 bits.

Comment: When I print out the array I get an empty square character printed between the actual values stored in the array.

Comment: @DSingh So you are printing the array from C, with something like printf? Could I see the code? As Jorn asked, what is the type of map? If you are trying to print out UTF-16 characters as regular C characters that would explain the problem.

Comment: The map is a 2d char array I've got as a global varialbe. I've also got a print function in JNI to print out the map once it's populated in C. EDIT contains print function.

Comment: @DSingh Ok then that is your problem right there. A jchar is a 16-bit value but a char in C is 8 bits. You should be using wchar_t instead of char for your map.

Comment: @DSingh To clarify, when you are doing the memcpy you are including the entire 16 bit value, which is why you are getting null bytes in your char array. You need to make the types match or convert the 16 bit unicode value into an 8 bit char, which is easy if you know each 16 bit character maps only to ASCII, and quite a bit more complicated if not.